# Retrieving data from multiple tables mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables MOVIES and SHOWS.

**MOVIES** tables contains:

```
id, name, image, description.
```

**SHOWS** table contains:

```
id, movieid, description.
```

I'm executing mysql statement to retrieve records from SHOWS table, i'm getting all the records normally. Again I'm executing another mysql statement to get image from MOVIES table based on movies table id which i'm getting from first query.
Is there any simple way to retrieve all the records from SHOWS table along with movie image?

These are my queries:

```
$qry1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shows WHERE id='1'"); 
$res = mysql_fetch_array($qry1); 
$movieid = $res['movieid']; 
$qry2 = mysql_query("SELECT image FROM movies WHERE id='$movieid'");
```

Comment: provide query in question

Comment: Hint:  `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: These are my queries

$qry1 = mysql_query(SELECT * FROM shows WHERE id='1');
$res = mysql_fetch_array($qry1);
$movieid = $res['movieid'];
$qry2 = mysql_query(SELECT image FROM movies WHERE id='$movieid');

Comment: SELECT * FROM SHOWS as s
INNER JOIN MOVIES as m 
ON m.id = s.movieid WHERE s.field = $var;    Use * in select query is not best practices.

Comment: God it @pdshah3690. Working fine now. Tq

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  t1.id, t1.movieid, t1.description, t2.image FROM SHOWS as t1
INNER JOIN 
MOVIES as t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Some sql join [docs](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

or you can try this, i was not sure witch id is from where:

```
SELECT id, movieid, description, image FROM SHOWS 
INNER JOIN MOVIES
ON id = movieid
```

Some foreign key [docs](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Here I am writing with out join you can all so use nested select queries

```
select movies.image from movies where movies.id in(Select shows.movieid form shows where shows.id= 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve data from multiple tables from one server at the same time. There is a lot of ways to achieve this operation which is called `join`. One of the possibility would be the `LEFT JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT t1.field1, t1.field2,..., t2.field1, t2.field2, ..., t2.fieldn
FROM table1 AS t2 
LEFT JOIN talble2 AS t2 ON t2.some_field = t1.anothed_filed
WHERE some_condition
```

In you case:

```
SELECT s.*, m.image
FROM SHOWS AS s
LEFT JOIN movies AS m ON s.movieid = m.id
WHERE some_condition
```

for more info see the documentation on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html